# Visual Studio can't find dll files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, linker-errors, libraries

I use VS2017 and want to create a C++ programm which needs a library for a microcontroller.

1. I downloaded the library from the companies website, unpacked the folder and copied it into my project folder.
2. Next step was **Properties** > **C/C++** > **Additional Include Directories** and inserted the path to the folder where the *.h file is located.
3. Then **Linker** > **Additional Library Directories** > **General** and inserted the path which leads to the folder where the *.lib file is stored.
4. Afterwards **Linker** > **Input** > **Additional Dependencies** here I filled in the name of my *.lib file (like "xyz.lib")
5. Finally I moved the *.dll file in the Debug-Folder.

(I don't know if this is an relevant information, but the *.h and *.lib file are in the same folder.)

The problem I'm facing right now is an error when I want to Debug my 
programm. The Error Message says:

> "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."

I did some research and found out that this is often linked to an missing *.dll file, so I used the programm *Dependencies* to analyse my executable file. Surprisingly the programm shows that my included *.dll file is missing.

At this point I'm stuck. I looked at several websites to find a solution but none of then could help me.

**UPDATE:**
I'm able to build my project succesfully, but not to debug it. I don't know if this might help.

What are some measures to fix this error? Any thoughts on this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The message box should tell you which dll is missing, just put it alongside your executable.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher The message box just says 
"The thread 0x317c has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
The program '[12424] BitScope_Micro_v1.2.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b)."
And this is the only external .dll file I use, and it is next to my executable.

Comment: In that case, it's not because it cannot find the dll. It may be that it's the wrong version of the dll, failing during startup?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher what do you mean with wrong version? I just changed the environment settings to 64-bit and I get an error that the library type conflicts with machine type. So I am pretty sure the version is correct

Comment: I mean does the .lib match the .dll version. Or could there be another conflict between global variables in the two?

Comment: Did you try to move everything in one folder, and run it outside of visual studio?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I basically don't know. How can I check this? Besides that I assume that the versions match since I downloaded it from the original website.

Comment: @VictorPadureanu you mean just try to start the .exe file without visual studio? If this is the case, yes I already did that and got the same message.

Comment: And you did not link with debug and use release or the other way around?

Comment: @VictorPadureanu no just double checked this. In the property settings I have "Debug" and "Active(Win32)". In the debuging section I have "Debug | x86 | Local Windows Debugger". So in my opinion this should be alright.

Comment: I was asking for Additional Library Directories to link to the right path and the dll to be used from the right path

Comment: Is it also a debug library, also built with the same compiler, with the same runtime?

Comment: @VictorPadureanu yes the paths are correct. The „Additional Library Directories“-path leads to the .lib file. And as I commented before, the .dll is next to my executable **and** in my project folder

Comment: Did you try the release configuration? It's a bit easier to install the required runtimes if it is not linked to the same runtime.

Comment: @VictorPadureanu I changed the property settings for the release configuration and tried to debug it this way. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: Not only the property setting, but also the linked binaries ( the .lib and the .dll ) to be from release

Comment: @VictorPadureanu I moved the .dll file to the new Releas folder. Is there anything additional I should change?

Comment: When you get an sdk, you usually have a release and a debug binary. Do you have the 2 versions? Did you try using the release version?

Comment: @VictorPadureanu I'm sorry but I just got an folder which includes a *.def ; *.h ; *.lib ; *.pas file, and a additional folder with some textfiles which are about license and fixes

Comment: There is only one thing that comes to mind, and if this doesn't work I don't know how can it be fixed. Try to install Microsoft Visual C++ <x> Redistributable. Where <x> can be 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 ... You might be missing the runtime on your computer. You should install the one that the dll was build to.

Comment: @VictorPadureanu I looked at the Fixes.txt file, there it says this library was updated 2015. So installed the MS C++ Redistributable 2015 both, 32 and 64 bit. To be on the safe side I also installed the 2012 version. Afterwards I rebooted my PC to make sure everything is up-to-date. 
But I get the same error again. Nevertheless, thank you for your support :-)